# Multiple command alias's

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, my current folder structure has a subfolder called `commands` and inside of it are a bunch of files named `x.js` for commands. One of these is a `version.js` and I want to be able to add an alias to this so people don't need to type out `!version` all the time. However the problem I have with this is that I need to update both files and I was wondering (haven't had much luck with searches) if there's a way to either have my bot read `!vers` as `!version` or just always fetch the same code from `version` every time `!vers` is ran.

Here's the code I use to go about loading the commands and detection which is selected.

```
const init = async() => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  // Here we load **commands** into memory, as a collection, so they're accessible here and everywhere else.
  const cmdFiles = await readdir("./commands/");
  client.logger.log("Loading a total of ${cmdFiles.length} commands.");
  cmdFiles.forEach(f => {
    if (!f.endsWith(".js")) return;
    const response = client.loadCommand(f);
    if (response) console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Any help or atleast points to the right direction would be appreicated :D

Comment: `ln -s commands/vers.js commands/version.js`

Comment: Sorry, It might be my lack of experience with js, But how do i add this into my code?

Comment: It's a bash command. Run it in your terminal. See [man ln](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html).